# How can I delete the letter in string

Tags: python, string

How can I remove a letter from string in python.
For example, I have the word "study", I will have a list something like this "tudy","stdy","stuy","stud". 
I have to use something like

```
   for i in range(len(string)):
        sublist.append(string0.replace(string[i], ""))
```

It works well. However, if I change the word "studys", when it replaces s with "", two s will disappear and It not works anymore (tudy instead study/tudys). I need help

Comment: What is the goal of removing a single letter from `study` ?

Comment: replace(string[i], "", 1)

Comment: @LinPy eventhough this replaces one character, but it will always replace the first occurrence of the character, hence the first and the last element in the sublist will be same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one:

```
s = 'studys'
lst = [s[:index] + s[index + 1:] for i in range(len(s))]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['tudys', 'sudys', 'stdys', 'stuys', 'studs', 'study']
```

Explanation:

Your code did not work because `replace` finds all the occurrences of the character in the word, and replaces them with the character you want. Now you can specify the number of counts to replace, as someone suggested in the comments, but even then replace checks the string from the beginning. So if you said, `string.replace('s','',1)` it will check the string from the start and as soon as it finds the first `'s'` it will replace it with `''` and break, so you will not get the intended effect of removing the character at the current index.

Comment: `sublist = [s[:index] + s[index + 1:] for index, _ in enumerate(s)]`

Comment: @SayandipDutta Oh my bad

Comment: @AlexandreS "Beautiful is better than ugly. Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex." ;)

Comment: @Sayse added explanation.

Comment: @AlexandreS I don't think Ramond Hettinger has anything against list comprehensions, I guess I could make `i` to `index`. And @AlexandreS `enumerate` in this case useless, as you need only the index, not the element at that index.

Comment: @ababak @Sayandip I don't like abbreviated variables, but I used your `s` variable. And I find `enumerate()` more readable than `range(len())` even if I don't like the `index, _`